# How to get the date in Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Source code shown below,

Database:

```
static func insertErrorLog(moduleName: String, message: String) {
    let dateToday = Date()
    let timestamp = Int(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)

    let db = Firestore.firestore()

    let docData: [String: Any] = [
        KDB.Fields.moduleName : moduleName,
        KDB.Fields.message : message,
        KDB.Fields.createdAt : dateToday
    ]
```

Model:

```
var uploadedAt: String = ""
var createdAt: String = ""

init(document: DocumentSnapshot) {
    self.key = document.documentID

    let json = JSON(document.data())

    self.storeId = json[KDB.Fields.storeId].stringValue
    self.imgName = json[KDB.Fields.imgName].stringValue
    self.title = json[KDB.Fields.title].stringValue
    self.description = json[KDB.Fields.description].stringValue
    self.sort = json[KDB.Fields.sort].intValue
    self.uploadedAt = json[KDB.Fields.uploadedAt].stringValue
    self.createdAt = json[KDB.Fields.createdAt].stringValue
}

init(key: String, storeId: String, imgName: String, title: String, description: String, sort: Int, uploadedAt: String, createdImageAt: String = "") {
    self.key = key
    self.storeId = storeId
    self.imgName = imgName
    self.title = title
    self.description = description
    self.sort = sort
    self.uploadedAt = uploadedAt
    self.createdAt = createdImageAt
}
```

Controller:

```
    query.getDocuments { (querySnapshot, error) in
        if let error = error {
            SpeedLog.print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        } else {
            var loop = 1
            for document in (querySnapshot?.documents)! {
                SpeedLog.print("documentDATA:\(document.data())")
                var photoObject = Photo(document: document)
                SpeedLog.print("photoObject:\(photoObject)")

                if (!photoObject.imgName.isEmpty) {
                    let storagePath = "\(photoObject.imgName)"
                    SpeedLog.print("Photo storagePath: \(storagePath)")

                    let storage = Storage.storage()
                    let storageRef = storage.reference()
                    let imageRef = storageRef.child(storagePath)

                    imageRef.getData(maxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024) { data, error in
                        if let error = error {
                            SpeedLog.print("Photos download image error documentID:\(document.documentID) : \(error.localizedDescription)")
                        } else {
                            photoObject.imageData = UIImage(data: data!)
                            self.photos.append(photoObject)

                            if loop == 1 {
                                self.imageView.image = photoObject.imageData!
                                self.photoTitleLabel.text = "\(photoObject.title)"

                                    self.photoCreatedAtLabel.text = "\(photoObject.createdAt)"
                                    self.photoCreatedAtTitleLabel.isHidden = false
                                //}
                            }
                        }
                        self.collectionView.reloadData()
                        loop += 1
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

extension PhotoGalleryViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return photos.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CellPhotoGallery", for: indexPath) as! PhotoGalleryCollectionViewCell

    configureCell(cell, atIndexPath: indexPath)

    return cell
}

func configureCell(_ cell: PhotoGalleryCollectionViewCell, atIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let photo = photos[indexPath.row]

    if let image = photo.imageData {
        cell.imageView.image = image
    }
    photoLabel.text = photo.title
    photoCreatedAtLabel.text = photo.createdAt
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let photo = photos[indexPath.row]

    if let image = photo.imageData {
        imageView.image = image
    }
    photoLabel.text = photo.title
    photoCreatedAtLabel.text = photo.createdAt
}
```

In Firebase we have field createdAt: (Timestamp)

Basically, when I run the codes in Xcode the Photo Storage fetch the createdAt from the firebase data but when it comes to Photo Object"self.photoCreatedAtLabel.text = "(photoObject.createdAt)" the date didn't shown. What is the possible missing in the codes? Please see attached of application for reference.

Edit: added a console printout of the photo object.

```
photoObject:Photo (
   key: "x2q0Asfjn2S8FYr6fIvA", 
   storeId: "", 
   imgName: "locator/stores/egdupo/BitoysVulcanizingandTireShop_rJTM7alkTp_M6L.jpg", 
   imageData: nil, 
   title: "", 
   description: "", 
   sort: 1, 
   uploadedAt: "", 
   createdAt: ""
)
```

[image: Date Uploaded 2 of 2]

Anyone?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please include only _relevant_ code in your question. Read [mcve] and then [edit] your question showing the _minimum_ code that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Have you checked that the createdAt property actually contains your date string?

Comment: Inside your *for document...* loop, if you add *print(document)* or after the *var photoObject...* and then *print(photoObject)*, what's the output? Can you copy and paste that output of one document or object in your question (as text!) so we can see what's being stored in the object?

Comment: I've checked the createdAt property contains timestamp in firebase while on the source code property contains string. @andlin

Comment: photoObject:Photo(key: "x2q0Asfjn2S8FYr6fIvA", storeId: "", imgName: "locator/stores/egdupo/BitoysVulcanizingandTireShop_rJTM7alkTp_M6L.jpg", imageData: nil, title: "", description: "", sort: 1, uploadedAt: "", createdAt: "") @Jay

Comment: I've tried to change the timestamp in firebase into string and the date fetching correctly. It means I need to set the code as timestamp not in string value?

Comment: It's a good idea to put structures and code in your question as it makes it easier to read. *paste that output of one document or object in your question (as text!)* I did that for you. Also, See my answer as it may provide a solution - however, I don't know why you're doing this *let json = JSON(document.data())* as it's not needed to access the fields of the document.

Comment: No luck I've tried to set the createdAt into Date but it doesn't work my code. Any solution? Big help! Will try this one again. Hope it will run smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

From the FireStore docs

> Currently, Firestore returns timestamp fields as Date but Date only
>   supports millisecond precision, which leads to truncation and causes
>   unexpected behavior when using a timestamp from a snapshot as a part
>   of a subsequent query.

So if you want to use it, your code needs to handle it as a NSDate (Date) object. however, using the following code

```
let settings = Firestore.firestore().settings
settings.areTimestampsInSnapshotsEnabled = true
```

> Setting timestampsInSnapshots to true will cause Firestore to return
>   Timestamp values instead of Date, which avoids truncation. Note that
>   you must also change any code that uses Date to use Timestamp instead.

In practice, assume we have a collection of documents and one of the fields in each document is called stamp; written like this

```
let now = Date()
let stamp = Timestamp(date: now)
self.db.collection("timestamps").document("test_stamp_0").setData( [
   "stamp": stamp
])
```

to then read that stamp node and format it for output in a UI

```
//read the document
if let stamp = document.get("stamp") {
    let title = document.documentID
    let ts = stamp as! Timestamp //force downcast stamp to a Timestamp cause' that's what it is.
    let aDate = ts.dateValue()
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ"
    let formattedTimeZoneStr = formatter.string(from: aDate)
    print(title, formattedTimeZoneStr) //prints test_stamp_0, 2018-10-03 08:00:00 -0400
}
```

Comment: No luck I've tried to set the createdAt into Date but it doesn't work my code. Any solution? Big help! Will try this one again. Hope it will run smoothly.

Comment: @AnneBernadette You may want to update your question with updated code - you're forcing it to be a string in multiple locations which may be part of the issue. Also, you're using JSON (per my comment to your question) which is not needed and may be complicating the issue further.